# How can I change the value of static public variables

Tags: c#, variables

```
static public charchar box1 = ' ', box2 = ' ', box3 = ' ', box4 = ' ', box5 = ' ', box6 = ' ', box7 = ' ', box8 = ' ', box9 = ' ', input2;

static public void reset()
{
    char box1 = ' ', box2 = ' ', box3 = ' ', box4 = ' ', box5 = ' ', box6 = ' ', box7 = ' ', box8 = ' ', box9 = ' ', input2;
    bool isWin = false;
    int line = 1, nrJogada = 1;
    ciclo();
}
```

Well, what I'm doing is clearly not working, I have searched for a long time on how to do this, but I can't (sorry I couldn't get the code snippet to work)
How can I change the vale of a public/private variable? (It will be used to reset the game

Comment: What is "charchar"? And what error message are you getting? Does the error message maybe indicate a solution?

Comment: in your reset you are declaring local variables with the same names as your statics.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `reset` method is declaring new local variables hiding the public fields. Remove the `char` and replace `,` with `;`!

```
static public void reset()
{
    box1 = ' ';
    box2 = ' ';
    box3 = ' ';
    box4 = ' ';
    box5 = ' ';
    box6 = ' ';
    box7 = ' ';
    box8 = ' ';
    box9 = ' ';
    bool isWin = false;
    int line = 1, nrJogada = 1;
    ciclo();
}
```

The other local variables `isWin`, `line` and `nrJogada` will be lost once the `reset` method terminates, as @Rob points out.

Also here, an array would be handier.

```
public static char[] box = new char[8] {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '};
public static char input2;

private static bool isWin = false;
private static int line = 1, nrJogada = 1;

static public void reset()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < box.Length; i++) {
        box[i] = ' ';
    }
    isWin = false;
    line = 1; nrJogada = 1;
    ciclo();
}
```

Note, writing the type name before a variable name, declares a new variable.

Comment: so what about isWin, line and nrJogada?

Comment: Also probably initializing the array in a static class constructor, so you avoid assigning ' ' twice in your code. I would probably rename `reset` to `Initialize` and call it from the static constructor.